# CASE with EXISTS query in SQlite returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sqlite, case, exists

I have 2 models:

- Products - list of products with their prices
- Offers - Product can have 0...n different offers

Tables structure:

```
Table [shop_product]
    Fields: 10
        [id]: integer NOT NULL
        [name]: varchar(300) NOT NULL
        [slug]: varchar(150) NOT NULL
        [description]: text NOT NULL
        [photo]: varchar(100) NOT NULL
        [price]: decimal NOT NULL
        [category_id]: integer NOT NULL
        [upload_date]: datetime NOT NULL
        [is_enabled]: bool NOT NULL
        [info_template_id]: integer

Table [shop_productoffer]
    Fields: 6
        [id]: integer NOT NULL
        [price]: decimal NOT NULL
        [description]: text NOT NULL
        [offer_attribute_id]: integer NOT NULL
        [product_id]: integer NOT NULL
        [default_offer]: bool NOT NULL
    Foreign Keys:
        [] ([product_id]) REFERENCES [shop_product]([id])
```

I would like to build a query which returns list of products and present 'default_price' field by the following logic:
if a product have offer(s) --> show the lowest related offer price
otherwise show price field from product

Here is what I got (SQlite3 query):

```
SELECT
product.price,
CASE offer.price
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM shop_productoffer
                WHERE shop_productoffer.product_id = product.id)
    THEN (SELECT MIN(price) FROM shop_productoffer
        WHERE shop_productoffer.product_id = product.id AND
        shop_productoffer.default_offer = 1)
    ELSE product.price
END AS 'default_price'
FROM shop_product as product
LEFT JOIN shop_productoffer AS offer ON product.id = offer.product_id
```

As it looks like, the `Exists` condition is never satisfied - query always return default_price' value as `product.price`. Some products are linked to offers and some of them are not but result is always same.

Am I doing something wrong? 
It's a very simple query but I can't make it work

Comment: Could you please share you tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach might be to have an aggregate query to produce the lowest offer and `left join` it to the `product` table:

```
SELECT    p.name, COALESCE(o.default_price, p.price) AS default_price
FROM      shop_product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   product_id, MIN(price) AS default_price
           FROM     shop_prodcutoffer
           WHERE    default_offer = 1
           GROUP BY product_id) o ON p.id = o.product_id
```

Comment: your approach works fine, I'm wondering why mine is not. As it seems the WHEN  condition is never met - I tried to put few trivial WHEN ("TRUE") conditions but result is always coming from the "ELSE" block.

Comment: @Ofir Your approach should work, but you're using the syntax incorrectly - you have `case price when ...` - meaning you'll attempt to compare the value of the `when` clause to the row's `price` value - which is probably never `true`, but some decimal value. I think you meant to use `case /*  note no price here! */ when exists (select...) then (select...) else product.price end`